# Delimiter Warning in shell Script with psql

Tags: shell, sh, eof, psql, delimited

I get a Delimter Error in a Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

result=`psql -d databasename -t -A <<EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table
WHERE "column_name_x" = 'specific_value_x'
AND "column_name_y" = 'specific_value_y'
AND ("column_name_z" LIKE 'specific_z%' OR "column_name_za" LIKE 'specific_za%')
;`
EOF

echo $result
#EOF
```

The result of the Script is fine. But I get two warnings:

```
./filename.sh: line 13: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./filename.sh: line 9: EOF: command not found
```

What is the problems here? Thank you!

Comment: Have you indented the `EOF`?  It must start in column 0.

Comment: @cdarke thanks for your fast response! But no, no spaces or somethink like that before or afther the EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the start of your here-doc inside of your command, but the EOF is outside of your command.

```
result=`psql -d databasename -t -A <<EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.table
WHERE "column_name_x" = 'specific_value_x'
AND "column_name_y" = 'specific_value_y'
AND ("column_name_z" LIKE 'specific_z%' OR "column_name_za" LIKE 'specific_za%')
EOF
`
```

The `;` seems wrong here too (at least it threw an error for me).

Comment: Thanky you! That was the problem :). You saved me hours ;). Have a nice day!